# Fill PHP Sessions with default data

Tags: php, database, session

I'm currently building a little website from scratch. I use a custom SessionHandler to store my sessions in the database which seems to work fine. So as soon as the user logs in I can store the relevant information (for example language) in the session data.

However I would also like to store certain data for users that are not logged in (yet) - again mainly the selected language but also some other stuff. To keep things clean I'd like to set all these standard values in one place, as soon as there is a session without a valid login.

The best place should obviously be my handler, however I'm not sure which function to use and how to get my data in there. I've attached the important parts of the code below.

I'm sure there is a simple solution for it, but so far I haven't gotten there. And it's also a terrible problem to google for ..

Thanks for the help!

```
public function __construct() {

    $this->databaseController = new DatabaseController();

    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', SESSION_MAX_LIFETIME);
    ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
    ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);

    session_set_save_handler(
        array($this, "_open"),
        array($this, "_close"),
        array($this, "_read"),
        array($this, "_write"),
        array($this, "_destroy"),
        array($this, "_gc")
    );
}

public function _open() {
    return $this->databaseController->check();
}

public function _close() {
    return $this->databaseController->close();
}

public function _read($id) {
    $result = $this->databaseController->getFirstRow("SELECT sessionData FROM bf1_sessions WHERE sessionID = '".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'");

    if (!empty($result['sessionData'])) {
        return $result['sessionData'];
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}

public function _write($id, $data) {
    $access = time();
    $result = $this->databaseController->executeQuery("REPLACE INTO bf1_sessions (sessionID, sessionAccess, sessionData) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."', '".intval($access)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."')");
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since I've never really used custom session handlers, I had to read the documentation a bit.  This will be more psuedo-code, but it should get you in the right direction.  Anytime you start a session, it will first call `open()` and then `read(string $sessionId)`.  You are currently selecting session data from the database and returning the serialized data or a blank string (as you should).  Instead of returning the blank string, you should just be able to return a serialized string of your default data.

```
public function _read($id) {
    $result = $this->databaseController->getFirstRow("SELECT sessionData FROM bf1_sessions WHERE sessionID = '".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'");

    if (!empty($result['sessionData'])) {
        return $result['sessionData'];
    }
    else {
        return serialize(array(
            'foo' => 'bar',
            'test' => 123
        ));
    }
}
```

Please note the above may not work exactly as expected.  I am assuming that the serialized data is meant to be a simple array of key/value pairs like in my above example.  Also, `serialize()` may not do exactly what you expect it too due to the following notice on the `session_set_save_handler()` documentation:

> While the data looks similar to serialize() please note it is a different format which is speficied in the session.serialize_handler ini setting.

A final thought: you shouldn't actually need to write this default data to the database, since every time you save/close the session `write($sessionId, $data)` is called with **all** of the data (instead of just the changes).  So you should be fine to just return default data on `read()` and save everything anytime `write()` is called. I'm just mentioning this, because there is a *chance* something weird happens and you *may* need to actually `INSERT INTO` the default data before returning it in your `read()` function.  Please comment if you any problems implementing this.

---

**Links:**

- [`session_set_save_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)
- [`serialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)
- [`session.serialize_handler`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler)

Comment: The method names had the _ because I had copied parts from a tutorial - I removed those now.

Comment: Your function is pretty close to what I came up with so far. However it does not work since the read()-method doesn't require a key for the data array but the session id to read that array. I'll keep trying to figure out a way to make it work.

Comment: You need to better explain what the current methods do and what 'sessionData' contains instead of blindly -1'ing my answer.

Comment: I did not down vote your answer - I don't even have enough reputation to use that feature. I have currently put this problem on hold, I'm trying to figure out if I can work my way around it without using default data at all.

Comment: @asto sorry for thinking you downvoted, I've read up a bit on custom sessions and updated my answer with some psuedo-code that should get you where you need to be.